# LCD Display 128x64 weird pin, C86 (input)

Tags: lcd

I got some LCD display from my friend. Base on the model number (TopWay LM6023) printed on product, I found the data sheet from google. According to the [datasheet](https://github.com/allenchak/LM6023/blob/master/Datasheet/SP-MCU-20110107-01_LM6023A-Manual-Rev0.3.pdf), it is a 128*64 LCD display, but I am confusing the pin out does not same/similar to the famous one. I read the datasheet, there are C86 pin. I have no idea what’s that, and how to make it work. I created a [github repo](https://github.com/allenchak/LM6023), I am wonder if someone could help to write an example code and wiring to Arduino UNO.

Moreover, I also would like to know what is 6800 & 8080 interface, is it Arduino UNO can simulate ? If yes, any reference?
[image: Terminal Functions]

Comment: the difference is how the Intel  8080 and the Motorola 6800 handle hardware I/O ..... the 6800 uses memory mapped I/O .... it uses an enable signal (pin10) and read/write select signal (pin9) ..... the 8080 uses ports for I/O .... you enable the write signal (pin9) if you are outputting data from the microcontroller and enable the read signal (pin10) if you are inputting data to the microcontroller

Comment: with the arduino, you probably want to use the serial interface, since it uses only two pins for the data  (pin17 and pin18 (need to verify pin numbers))

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately driving a graphic LCD is not as easy as driving one of the most popular type HD44780 LCD's.
Back to the subject:
If the state on this pin is HIGH then you shall use  Motorola's 6800 interface, when state on C86 is LOW, use Intel's 8080 interface.
Depending on your selection you would have to keep the communication standard. For 8080 interface refer to point 3.3.1 of you datasheet, for 6800 see point 3.3.2.
Note: If you are struggling, try to search for the libraries using controller's name: LM6023A or one of the S1D15300 or S1D16700
Also, consider number of pins available on your Arduino. It may be that you can drive this LCD with Arduino Uno using serial interface only. (See this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84841/which-interface-is-better-for-my-oled-display))

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your information are helpful after I read the link. Seems it is not a simple task could be complete within a day or week.

Comment: This is why sometimes is easier to search for readily available libraries. Unfortunately this one is none of the most popular. You can also check the big collection of the libraries under the name of u8glib - see the list of the supported lcd's: https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib/wiki/device